# Microsoft SQL Server Create a session specific synonym

Tags: sql-server, session, synonym

I am working on a database that hold specific session data in separate tables for each session. e.g. I'd have a table called ProductsABCD, which holds products visible to that session, where ABCD is the session Id.  Not graceful, but what I've got to work with. Currently I would access this data in the format:

```
DECLARE @Session AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ABCD'
DECLARE @strSQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @strSQL = 'SELECT * FROM Products' + @Session
EXEC (@strSQL)
```

A very simplified version, but anyone who has ever used Dynamic SQL will tell you how quickly this becomes very ugly. I am currently looking into the option of using Synonyms.  I can set these up in Dynamic SQL and then Access the synonym without dynamic. e.g.

```
DECLARE @Session AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ABCD'
DECLARE @strSQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @strSQL = 'CREATE SYNONYM myProducts FOR Products' + @Session
EXEC (@strSQL)

SELECT  * 
FROM    myProducts

DROP SYNONYM myProducts
```

While this works when only a single user is testing, its not a viable option when multiple users are online as the synonym is globally accessible. Does anyone know of a way to create a synonym that is only accessible to a single session at a time? Similar to how a temp table can only be accessed by a single session.

Many thanks.

Additional info:

The circumstances here are that there is some business logic at play here that defines what products are visible, what prices are displayed, what stock levels are accessible etc. Each of these is stored in global tables created upon session start up, and then cleaned up either at session dispose or on a timer.

These cannot be stored in temp tables, because the lifetime expires when the setup stored proc finishes. Cannot be held in a single table with a session parameter as a field because of the high number of sessions/qty of data that is available in the system. This was developed before partitioning was really an option. Would also require major reworking of stored procedures - please remember this is an inherited existing system.

A db session here is an IIS session that opens a single connection to the database and holds that session open.  This is then cleared down by a dispose session sent on log out, or via a timer that clears any old sessions that were not disposed of properly.

I would be looking for a synonym that is unique either for the period of the connection, or only during the specific call to a stored procedure.  Either would work, provided the synonym is not available to another session or stored procedure.

Comment: Pretty obscure sutiation and solution concept. What is a "session" here? Why session has own global persistent objects? What if session interrupts or someone starts many sessions at a time?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Added more detail to main question - hope that clears it up. The package I'm working is "unique" to be polite!

Comment: Do different sessions run under the same login (db principal)?

Comment: Same user name, but individual connections per request.  So for example I would open a connection, setup the session data and close the connection. Then to read, we would open a new connection, read the session data and close the connection.etc.etc.  We do not hold a single connection open.

Answer (score 1):

Possible way to circumvent this quest is to create per-session user, put all tables in per-session schema, make this schema default to this user, run everything with `execute as <session-user>` and without specifying schemas before tables. Could do the thing - to keep tables with same name (but in different schemas). But you better have hothing in `dbo` schema in this case. And maybe try to rethink whole solution someday.

Comment: I like this idea, I'm not sure if its going to work with my current implantation - but that's because of items outside of the database rather than the approach itself.  I'm going to give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: I have looked into this and come across a problem.  When select is called within procedure the precedence for location is sys schema, procedures native schema, database default schema.  The users default schema is not considered.  The Users schema only comes into play if you use dynamic SQL and coming away from Dynamic is the whole reason for this part of the project. Any way around this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is a little bit old but here is another way that may help

Logic:

- Create 2 tables to save your tables friendly names (to write the query) and real name (to execute)
- Write the query with normal names in the `@friendlyQuery` variable
- The `@realQuery` is going the replace all the names and execute

Warning: Be careful with short names like "#A" because another name can replace too, or use the `quotename` in all the names like the example

Code:

```
create table #realTables (
    friendlyName varchar(100) unique
    ,realName varchar(100) )
create table #myTemps (
    friendlyName varchar(100) unique
    ,uniqueName varchar(100) default '##' + replace(newid(),'-',''))

    --Write your tables names variables

insert #realTables              values ('[productsTable]', '[productsTableABCD]')
insert #myTemps (friendlyName)  values ('[#products]')

    --Write your friendly query

declare @friendlyQuery varchar(max) = '
select top 1000
    *
into [#products]
from [productsTable]'
declare @realQuery varchar(max) = @friendlyQuery
select
    @realQuery = REPLACE(@realQuery, friendlyName, realName)
from #realTables
select
    @realQuery = REPLACE(@realQuery, friendlyName, uniqueName)
from #myTemps

print '-------> friendlyQuery' + char(13) + @friendlyQuery
print '-------> realQuery' + char(13) + @realQuery
EXEC(@realQuery) --> Magic
```

Plus: If you need to get the data into friendly table names, use the [PRC_MATCH_INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787634/automatically-match-columns-in-insert-into-select-from/71947217#71947217) like the last example

Comment: Hi Erick. Thanks for the reply.  While the solution would work, we are trying to minimise the amount of dynamic sql in use.  Some of the general support team aren't as "comfortable" with tracing through dynamic.  This may well help someone else though.

Comment: It is absolutely better to minimise the dynamic sql so everyone can easily understand, data structure and indexes is the right way for this correction